# awk script to remove trailing and leading underscores

Tags: awk

To keep lines which have numbers below  100(hundred) on their third field, how can I deal with trailing and leading underscores using  awk script.

Here is sample input:

```
asd 5.0 _84_ 34
sds 3.8 _340_ 56
sds 3.8  99 56
sds 3.8 _340_ 56          
ddd 288 _26_ 45
sdf 321 _374_ 53 
tyu 321 _39_ 89 
sds 3.8 120 56 
wer 3.8 _28_ 345
sds 3.8  45 56
tre 230 _265_ 90  
rtu 389 _372_ 45
bnm 965 _270_ 745
fgh 856 _44_ 346
sds 3.8 107 56
```

expected output will be:

```
 asd 5.0 _84_ 34
 sds 3.8  99 56            
 ddd 288 _26_ 45
 tyu 321 _39_ 89 
 wer 3.8 _28_ 345
 sds 3.8  45 56       
 fgh 856 _44_ 346
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this, for example:

```
$ awk -F_ '$2>=100' file
_340_ 
_374_  
_265_  
_372_ 
_270_
```

#### Explanation

- `-F_` defines `_` as the field separator.
- `$2>=100` gets those records whose 2nd field is bigger or equal to 100. In that case, it performs the default awk action: `{print $0}`.

Comment: it works in this case but what if there are other fields on each line , example: aa bc _84_ wer, se dffg _340_ er lmn....how can we deal with i.e if the numbers are on third field as shown...

Comment: Update your sample input, then. Obviously my answer was based on the sample input you gave :)